# Modulus of $\exp(-(A+iB)^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, gaussian

I know modulus of $e^z$ is just $e^{\Re(z)}$, and that $|A+iB| \geq A^2$. What I want to know is if the following holds true
$$
|e^{-(A+iB)^2}| \leq e^{-A^2}
$$

Comment: Take $A=0, B=1$.

Comment: What are $A,B$, real numbers, matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case when $A, B \in \mathbb{R},$ the answer is: "No". 
  The given condition holds if $B=0$.
Because, $|e^{-(A+iB)^2}| = |e^{-(A^2-B^2+2iAB)}|  = |e^{(B^2-A^2-2iAB)}| = |e^{(B^2-A^2)}*e^{-2iAB}|= |e^{(B^2-A^2)}|*|e^{-2iAB}|$ 
 Using $|e^{i*x}|=1$, for real $x,$ therefore $|e^{-2iAB}|=1,$ So $|e^{-(A+iB)^2}| = e^{(B^2-A^2)}. $
$|e^{-i*2AB}| \leq e^{-A^2} $ if and only if  $e^{(B^2-A^2)} \leq e^{-A^2}.$ 
 Therefore, $B^2-A^2 \leq -A^2,$ Hence $B^2 \leq 0.$ 
 Since $B  \in \mathbb{R},$ then $B=0.$ So, the given condition $|e^{-(A+iB)^2}|  \leq e^{-A^2} $ is true if $B=0.$


Counter-example has been given by Kavi Rama Murthy in the comment section just below the question.